# Flutter stuck on Running Gradle task bundleRelease

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I run `flutter build appbundle` stuck the terminal on `Running Gradle task bundleRelease...` . Can anyone help me?
I can't find anything on other forums.

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same problem once, and it was the slow internet that causes this, and also I had to turn on a VPN. Please try these solutions and let me know what happens.

Comment: Which vpn do you mean?

Comment: Any VPN could do the trick nothing in specific.